# is there a workaround for printing a google sheet using apps script - without the use of sensitive oauth scopes such as the html service

Tags: google-apps-script, printing

I'm trying to create a function that will print a particular sheet - but I want to retain the effectivness of @OnlyCurrentDoc. My end users don't know me so I need to avoid the authorisation step warning that tells you to proceed only if you know and trust the developer.

I've tried searching the documentation but can't find anything suitable.